# OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar returns null when the query returns value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am facing a problem with using OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar().

This is my query.

```
SELECT SUM(gobg.quan / d.coef) as quan 
FROM ((N_GOODS_EXTCODES AS nge 
INNER JOIN DRUGS AS d ON  nge.ec_NZOK20190816 = d.DrugCode) 
INNER JOIN N_GOODS AS ng ON nge.good_code = ng.code) 
INNER JOIN G_OBGS AS gobg ON ng.smg_id = gobg.smg_id 
WHERE nge.ec_NZOK20190816 = "AF063" AND gobg.part_num LIKE 'KR72K35*' ;
```

When I execute it in MS ACCESS this is the value that returns.

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixDOy.jpg)

This is my C# code

```
public double getGoodQuan(string goodCode, string goodPart, string pharmNzokList)
        {
            double result = 0;

            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringBuffer))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Queries.getGoodQuan(goodCode, goodPart, pharmNzokList), con))
                    {
                        result = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Program.ErrorLog(ex.Message, this.GetType().Name + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

public static string getGoodQuan(string goodCode, string goodPart, string pharmNzokList)
        {
            string result = "SELECT SUM(gobg.quan / d.coef) " +
                            "FROM ((N_GOODS_EXTCODES AS nge " +
                            "INNER JOIN DRUGS AS d ON  nge." + pharmNzokList + " = d.DrugCode) " +
                            "INNER JOIN N_GOODS AS ng ON nge.good_code = ng.code) " +
                            "INNER JOIN G_OBGS AS gobg ON ng.smg_id = gobg.smg_id " +
                            "WHERE nge." + pharmNzokList + " = \"" + goodCode + "\" " +
                            "AND gobg.part_num LIKE '" + goodPart + "*' " +
                            ";";
            return result;
        }
```

**After cmd.ExecuteScalar() result is aways null.**

I have tried to use string, double, object and the result is aways the same.

In the same project I am using the same code but with different query and it is working.

This is the query that works.

`SELECT SYS_PHARMA.pharm_nzok_list FROM SYS_PHARMA;`

And this is the MS ACCESS result

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iut5.jpg)

**What I am doing wrong with the first query that aways returns null?**

Comment: "After cmd.ExecuteScalar() result is aways null" do you mean `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` returns null? Can you also check with the debugger that `Queries.getGoodQuan(goodCode, goodPart, pharmNzokList)` produces the expected SQL?

Comment: `getGoodQuan` post this output please (it should be a `string` of the actual query). It seems the result set is either empty and or the column/row result is null. To make sure it's the actually query, replace the query itself with `SELECT 1 FROM SYS_PHARMA`, does the `result` now contain `1`?

Comment: @vc74 , Yes I did it already and returns the expected SQL

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, Yes the result constains 1.

Comment: @king that's good as it narrows the issue down to your actual query itself. Again, please post the `getGoodQuan` return value (should be a string) and or the code that produces the query; this is the issue. By they way I see you are new here, welcome to SO!

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, I just added to the post

Comment: I'm not an Access expert but are double and single quotes equivalent?

Comment: The `WHERE` statement is using `"` you need to replace them with `'` instead of them; see `\"" + goodCode + "\" "`. TBH you should be using parameters which helps to avoid things like this and helps prevent injection as well. @vc74 no they are not, OP should be using `'` instead of `"` in the condition.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Thanks for your help!

Comment: I assume this was the issue then?

Answer (score -1):

I found where the problem was.

In the WHERE clause I am using LIKE Operator with `*` in the end of the text because I want to search for everything that starts with that text(as the MS Access documentation says).

```
gobg.part_num LIKE 'KR72K35*'
```

Then I changed `*` to `%` and it worked! ExecuteScalar() returns the right value!

```
gobg.part_num LIKE 'KR72K35%'
```